# react-sparklines remove startSpot

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I use 'react-sparklines' and want simply remove start spot (like on the 1st example), but also change the spot color.

[image]

Here is the demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/2v7kkn19ky

Source code says: https://github.com/borisyankov/react-sparklines/blob/master/src/SparklinesSpots.js#L48

If I specify style, the startSpot will be shown.

How can I specify style and remove startSpot at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color of an `endSpot` is controlled by `spotColors` prop if there's no `style` so you can use it for customization:

```
  <Sparklines data={sparklineData} limit={20}>
    <SparklinesLine style={{ stroke: "#e18937", fill: "none" }} />
    <SparklinesSpots
      spotColors={{
        "-1": "red",
        "0": "black",
        "1": "#e18937"
      }}
      size={2.5}
    />
  </Sparklines>
```